# Block typing in any other alphabet than english

Tags: javascript, validation, ascii, fromcharcode

I know the JavaScript that restricts entering some special characters or number, etc using charcode and ascii value.

Is there anyway that I can block people entering any other language (I mean alphabet) expect English? More specifically how can I block people entering Chinese or some other non English alphabet name in the textbox and make them strictly enter only English alphabet name?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you have to use regexp either to block non-English characters or to allow just English characters

Comment: @dippas - you are legend mate :)

Comment: First you will have to define what "English" is. If you can actually define that, than you can block other languages. But in reality, you can't define that.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Sorry to be more specific I should block languages like Chinese, Japanese etc. which doesn't follow English alphabet. I am okay with any language that accepts English alphabet, I will edit my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @lock I think what you mean is the ASCII character set which only contains English alphabet and numbers and punctuations?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Exactly, you are correct. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this function to remove special characters from input

```
function removeSpecials(evt) {
var input = document.getElementById("myinput");
var patt = /[^\u0000-\u007F ]+/;
setTimeout(function() {
     var value = input.value;
     input.value = value.replace(patt,"");
 },100);
```

}

The point is: I create a pattern to detect all special characters

```
var patt = /[^\u0000-\u007F ]+/;;
```

and I replace the input value

```
value.replace(patt,"");
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nanndoj/s9h3pu56/5/)

Comment: This code is supposed to remove only form last typed char. I will change the example to remove all from the input. You have to use replace instead

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to block all non-ascii inputs would probably be

```
/^[\x00-\xff]+$/.test(input);
```

This expression will return `true` if `input` is composed of purely ascii characters.

It will return `false` if any non-ascii character is found.

---

You can adjust the range of accepted ascii characters to meet your needs. `\x00-\x55` includes ascii char codes `0-255`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily restrict the user to a specific character set by checking their input with something like `inputString.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)`. That will catch languages like Chinese, though there are plenty of languages which share almost the same alphabet as English and thus cannot be easily blocked.

Comment: Thanks mate, no problem. My main goal is to block languages like Chinese, Japanese, etc. which doesn't follow English alphabet.